# Are Typescript project references compiled into the target project?

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I have a monorepo with multiple packages being deployed as Lambda functions. These functions all require a shared library. The folder structure is as follows:

```
/
├─ lambda/
│  ├─ function1/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ dist/
│  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  ├─ function2/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ dist/
│  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  ├─ tsconfig.json
├─ lib/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ dist/
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
├─ tsconfig.base.json
```

In each package, I have the following tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": ".",

    "paths": {
      "@org/library": ["../../lib"]
    }
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../lib/"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's compiling fine, but I have two issues:

1. VSCode doesn't understand the path alias and, more importantly, (and likely the cause)
2. The code from the library isn't actually compiled into the package that will be deployed as a function

Am I missing something here? The library, and all its dependencies, would have to be compiled into each package along with that package's other dependencies...

I have `composite=true` in the `lib/tsconfig.json` but `composite=false` everywhere else. I believe that's the correct way... (I'm also tried setting `composite=true` everywhere)

I don't see how this could work in a monorepo case??

Comment: Did you figure it out? Running into the same issue

Comment: @AlexGogl nope. I don't think this approach is envisioned... I just had to write a few different scripts that I can run from the root...